# Keep getting Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null error flutter

Tags: flutter, null, boolean

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've looked over the code I currently have and it doesn't seem to make sense why it throws that error. I'm not entirely sure I understand what's wrong with my code.

Visual Studio Code tells me the error is at line 40 in the product_item class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import '../providers/product.dart';
import '../providers/cart.dart';
import '../providers/auth.dart';

class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
  // final String id;
  // final String title;
  // final String imageUrl;

  // ProductItem(this.id, this.title, this.imageUrl);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final product = Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: false);
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false);
    final authData = Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false);
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: GridTile(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
              ProductDetailScreen.routeName,
              arguments: product.id,
            );
          },
          child: Image.network(
            product.imageUrl,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        footer: GridTileBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
          leading: SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .020,
            child: Consumer<Product>(
              builder: (ctx, product, _) => IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  product.isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                ),
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                onPressed: () {
                  product.toggleFavoriteStatus(authData.token);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            product.title,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.shopping_cart,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              cart.addItem(product.id, product.price, product.title);
              Scaffold.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text(
                    'Added item to cart!',
                  ),
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                  action: SnackBarAction(
                    label: 'UNDO',
                    onPressed: () {
                      cart.removeSingleItem(product.id);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the product class where the program is supposed to get the favorited status of a product.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.description,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.imageUrl,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });

  void _setFavValue(bool newValue) {
    isFavorite = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> toggleFavoriteStatus(String token) async {
    final oldStatus = isFavorite;
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
    final url =
        'https://flutter-shopapp-b4a66-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products/$id.json?auth=$token';
    try {
      final response = await http.patch(
        url,
        body: json.encode({
          'isFavorite': isFavorite,
        }),
      );
      if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
        _setFavValue(oldStatus);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      _setFavValue(oldStatus);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I believe you are using an older version of Flutter that is not using null safety. That means that `isFavorite` could be `null`

Try to change this line

```
product.isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border
```

to

```
product.isFavorite == true ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border
```

Comment: yeah that worked thanks. Btw how can I know what version of Flutter I'm using?

Comment: try writing "flutter doctor"  in the terminal